# Iterate through/compare values in arrays and print string based on result, IndexError: out of bounds

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, iteration, compare

Trying to create a win/loss/tie list based on team scores. My attempt:

```
#import numpy
import numpy as np

#create array for week numbers
week_number = np.array(['Week 1','Week 2','Week 3','Week 4','Week 5','Week 6'])

#create arrays for scores
my_team_score = np.array([41,17,28,21,10,18])
opposing_team_score = np.array([33,11,30,28,17,30])

#create iteration to check win, tie, or loss and print result
for i in my_team_score:
    if my_team_score[i] > opposing_team_score[i]:
        print(week_number[i] + ': Win')
    elif my_team_score[i] == opposing_team_score[i]:
        print(week_number[i] + ': Tie')
    else:
        print(week_number[i] + ': Loss')
```

Receiving error:

```
IndexError: index 41 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

Comment: do `print(i)` you'll get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over an iterable, what you have is a value itself, not an indice. Here `i` will value `41, 17, 28, 21, 10, 18`, at each iteration.

To get an indice you'd use `for i in range(len(my_team_score)):`

---

But use `zip` to get a nicer code

```
for a_score, b_score, week in zip(my_team_score, opposing_team_score, week_number):
    if a_score > b_score:
        print(week + ': Win')
    elif a_score == b_score:
        print(week + ': Tie')
    else:
        print(week + ': Loss')
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! That worked perfectly. As an aside -- could you please explain a bit more about `zip`?

Comment: @slightlyartistic take a few minute to google it and read about, I'm sure you'll understand, and you'll get it even easier as you'll see examples

Comment: I did, and you're right. I will practice with it and work to optimize my code. Thanks again!